# Is this a case for empty try catch blocks?

Tags: c#, exception

Let's assume that you read in a large XML file and about 25% of the nodes are optional, so you really don't care if they are there, however, if they are provided to you, you would still read them in and do something with them (store them in a db for example).

Since they are optional, isn't it OK in this case to wrap them in empty `try . . . catch` blocks, so in the event that they are not there, the program just continues execution?  You don't care about throwing an error or anything similar.

Keep in mind that just because they are optional does not mean you don't want to check for them. It just means that the person providing you with the XML either doesn't want you to know certain information or they do want you to know and it is up to you to handle it.

Finally, if this was just a few nodes, it wouldn't be a big deal, but if you have 100 nodes that are optional for example, it can be a pain to check if each one is `null` first or halting execution if a `null` was found, hence the reason why I asked if this is valid reason for empty try catch statements.

Comment: Don't use exceptions for flow control.  Put the null checks in.

Comment: @cadrell0 - That is one of my points, if there are a few null checks, it is fine, but what if you have 100's.

Comment: ...or make a smarter, more generic way of processing. Usually that's easily solved with e.g. a method (e.g. extension) per type of data (which would check both format on top of 'existence'), to check/load specifically - and then inside you can put the if properly (or along those lines, depends on the case, concrete example and concrete solution for it), there's always the way.

Comment: @Xaisoft if one null check is more efficient than one empty try-catch block, then hundreds of null checks are more efficient than hundreds of try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If processing node X is optional then your code should looks something like:

```
if(node X exists in file)
{
  do work with X
}
```

and not:

```
try
{
  do work with X
}
catch{}
```

Now if there is no way to determine if node X exists other than to try to use it, or if it's possible for node X to be removed after you check to see if it's there, then you're forced to use the try/catch model.  That isn't the situation here.  (As opposed to say, checking if a file exists before reading it; someone can delete it after you check to see if it's there.)

**------------------------------------------------------------**

**Edit:**

Since it seems your issue is to access node "grandchild" alone in the following XML in which 'Parent' may not exist.  (Please excuse my poor ability to render this XML in SO; knowledgeable readers feel free to edit in the appropriate formatting.)

```
<root>
  <Parent>
    <Child>
      <GrandChild>
        The data I really want.
      </GrandChild>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
</root>
```

For that I'd do something like this:

```
public static class XMLHelpers
{
public static Node GetChild(this Node parent, string tagName)
{
  if(parent == null) return null;
  return parent.GetNodeByTagName(tagName);
}
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var grandbaby = rootNode.GetChild("Parent").GetChild("Child").GetChild("GrandChild");
if(grandbaby != null)
{
  //use grandbaby
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general the scenario sounds like a borderline acceptable case for using an empty catch block (assuming of course the catch is scoped to the type of the exception thrown when there is no node).  Since you don't have any work to do if the node isn't present then the code execution will continue as planned.

I do question whether or not the pain of checking for `null` is too great here.  The amount of code / pain to check for null is 2 lines

```
if (parent.IsPresente("child")) {
  var child = parent.GetNode("child");
}
```

The overhead of a `try / catch` though is just as verbose

```
try { 
  DoSomething(parent.GetNode("child"));
} catch (TheExceptionType) { }
```

Given this choice I would choose the `if` approach.  It's equally declarative, generally speaking faster and overall a better style.  Exceptions should really only be used for exceptional situations.  Stuff which can't be prevented before hand.  This is a very preventable situation and could potentially even be made more palatable with an extension method to support the pattern

```
XmlNode child;
if (parent.TryGetNode("child", out child)) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: Yes, the execution of the program is not dependent on the node.  When I said pain, I meant the possibility of having 100s of nested nodes which would cause one gigantic nested if statement.

Comment: @Xaisoft ok, i think i see the scenario a little better here.  You're basically saying it's not a series of sybling nodes but rather a deeply nested traversal.

Comment: @Xaisoft We would need to know more about the program to attempt any sort of generalization, but for example in JaredPar's code having DoSomething work correctly even if `null` is passed in can move the null check to one helper method rather than the 100 calls to it.

Comment: @Xaisoft have you considered using an xpath query for the deep nesting?

Comment: @JaredPar - No I have not, can you provide a small example as I am not too familiar with xpath

Comment: @Xaisoft I'm not familiar with xpath either (though I'm sure someone on stackoverflow is). Generally though it's a feature for doing XML queries and I believe could be used to do a deeply nested query to check for the existence or not of the particular node.

Comment: @Xaisoft See the edit to my answer, it addresses the issues you've raised in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Since they are optional, isn't it OK in this case to wrap them in
>   empty try catch blocks so in the even that they are not there, the
>   program just continues execution.

No - instead you should check whether the particular node exists before doing anything else. Since you *expect* this to be the case sometimes, your program logic should cover this, this is not a use case for exception handling.

Comment: This is rhetorical question, but what about nested nodes, lets say for example there are 10 or more nested nodes, wouldn't that cause one big If null, if null, if null.... statement.

Comment: @Xaisoft Not really.  You just nest the if checks inside of each other .  `if(have(A)){if(have(B)){use A+B}}`  (please use linebreaks when not using in a SO comment.)

Comment: @Servy - You have a point, I guess it is only a pain in the beginning, right?